# How to set a default value when unmarshal a json to struct

Tags: json, go

I want to set a default value to a field when unmarshal from a json string.
I know i can set the value i want before unmarshaling, I think it's not a beautiful way.
Is there any way else, like using a "default" tag?

```
func main() {
    in := "{}"
    myStruct := StructTest{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &myStruct)
    fmt.Println(myStruct)

}

type StructTest struct {
    V int64 `default:1`
}
```

Comment: `encoding/json` does not support anything like that.

Comment: so i have to set the default value in initialization?

Comment: You can set the default value yourself manually, and then, if the json does not contain a property that matches the field with the default value, that field will stay untouched when you unmarshal the json into the target struct.

Comment: is there any json lib else support this feather?

Comment: I don't know, maybe there is, maybe there isn't. If there isn't you can also implement a solution yourself. You could have, for example, a package `myjson` and a function `myjson.Unmarshal` which would use reflection to set the defaults first and then delegate to the `json.Unmarshal`... whether that's worth the trouble is for you to decide.

Comment: we have this wrapper logic in our project, just curious is there any official solution. thank you anyway

Comment: Nope, nothing "official", at least not in the standard lib.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is define a custom unmarshal function and decide there if you want to use the default value or not. In case you have other fields in `StructTest` you will want to create an alias for `StructTest` in `UnmarshalJSON` so that other fields will still be treated the same, while `V` will be overridden.

The snippet below shows one way to do it, also check out this [working Go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/5YgAoKTHBG1).

```
type StructTest struct {
    V     int64
    Other string // this field should be unmarshaled the regular way
}

func (st *StructTest) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // create alias to prevent endless loop
    type Alias StructTest
    tmp := struct {
        *Alias
        V *int64
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(st),
    }

    // unmarshal into temporary struct
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // check if V was supplied in JSON and set default value if it wasn't
    if tmp.V == nil {
        st.V = 1 // default
    } else {
        st.V = *tmp.V
    }

    return nil
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

Actually for this simple example it can be done even simpler:

```
func (st *StructTest) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    st.V = 1 // set default value before unmarshaling
    type Alias StructTest // create alias to prevent endless loop
    tmp := (*Alias)(st)

    return json.Unmarshal(data, tmp)
}
```

Comment: Even shorter: json.Unmarshal(data, (*Alias)(st)) - no need to create a temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, and for cases like this:

```
type T struct {
    Field1 int
    Field2 int
}
...
func foo(data []byte) error {
    var x T
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // now set Field1 and/or Field2 to default values if needed
    // ... but this is hard to do ...
    use(x)
    return nil
}
```

it's simple and easy to do it the other way, i.e.:

```
func foo(data []byte) error {
    x := T{Field1: 99 /* red ballons */, Field2: 42 /* The Answer */ }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // now Field1 and/or Field2 are already set to default values if needed
    use(x)
    return nil
}
```

But what if the default is hard to compute?  For instance:

```
type T2 struct {
    Answer   int
    Question string
}
```

and function `foo` should have a default Answer of 42 as before, but the default Question [should be the one that the mice were trying to compute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), and obviously we don't want to spend a few millenia computing it if we don't have to.  So we can't *pre*-initialize `x`, and we need to know if a question was provided.<sup>1</sup>

Yet another alternative, of course, is to decode into a struct with a pointer, then convert that nullable thing to the struct that *doesn't* have a pointer; we know whether the nullable variant's field was filled in or not because it's non-nil if it was filled-in.  This produces code of this sort:

```
type T_ struct {
    Answer   int
    Question *string
}
```

and fill in one variable `x_` of type `T_`:

```
func foo(data []byte) error {
    var x T2
    x_ := T_{Answer: 42}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x_); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    x.Answer = x_.Answer
    if x_.Question = nil {
        x.Question = computeTheQuestion(x_.Answer)
    } else {
        x.Question = *x_.Question
    }
    use(x)
    return nil
}
```

However, once again I lament (at least slightly) the ability to unmarshal json data with code like this hypothetical interface:

```
func foo(data []byte) error {
    var objectish map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &objectish); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    x := T2{Answer: 42}
    if err := json.ReUnmarshal(objectish, &x); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // We now know that the object-ish decoded JSON has the right
    // "shape" for a T, and variable x is filled in with a default
    // Answer.  Its Question is the empty string if there was an
    // empty Question, or if there was *no* Question at all, so
    // now let's find out if we need to compute the right Question.
    if _, ok := objectish["Question"]; !ok {
        x.Question = computeTheQuestion(x.Answer)
    }
    use(x) // pass x to a hoopy frood
    return nil
}
```

This hypothetical `ReUnmarshal`—which could actually just be `Unmarshal` itself, really—would, if given an `interface{}`, treat its value as resulting from an earlier `Unmarshal` and just re-type the result.  If given a `map[string]interface{}` it would re-type the object.  If given a `map[string]map[string]interface{}` it would do the obvious thing here as well, and so on.  The only change the user sees is that `Unmarshal` (or `ReUnmarshal`, if changing the type signature is too rude) now takes:

- `[]byte`, or
- `string`, probably, just for convenience, or
- `json.RawMessage`, because that already does almost the right thing, or
- `map[string]T` for T being any of the types it accepts (including `map` recursively)

and it does the obvious thing with each of these.

Note that this is pretty similar to using `json.RawMessage`.  However, when using `json.RawMessage`, we're right back to writing out a variant of the original struct type, with the same field names.  See [this example in the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/13hVbizOFZt), where we have to declare `x_` (rather than `objectish`) with the type that uses the `json.RawMessage` argument.

(Alternatively, you can create a type with its own unmarshal function, as in [lmazgon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191145/1256452).  But again you must invent a type, rather than just decoding right into the already-supplied target type.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In this case, we could use `Question *string`, or assume that null strings are not allowed, or something, but this example is pretty reductionist.  Suppose instead that we're supposed to compute a bignum with an accurate pi to some number of places, or any other hard but realistic computation.  The point here is that there *can* be situations where pre-loading the defaults is relatively expensive, so we'd like to avoid that.